# multiple webbrowser control, separate cookies?

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I notice when I visit a certain page with the webbrowser-control I am logged in as the same user as I am in IE. I want to visit the same page as and not as the logged in user. How do I do this? I would hate to repeatedly log in and out.

-edit- **I no longer need this**. But I'll leave this question up.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you clear out the current session, the most likely place the logged in state will be stored.